css display block in order to stuck to input on top of each other
I'm try to understand how does CSS display property work, i wrote this simple html code:


<div>
  <form className="container" action="">
    <input name="fName" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value={props.fName}/>
    <input name="sName" placeholder="Second Name" type="text" value={props.sName} />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>



with this HTML the 2 input boxes are horizontally aligned but I want them to stay on top of each other, so I tried to apply some CSS style.
.container{
  text-align: center;
  display: block; 
}

why is the display block not working as expected? should not be applied to the child as well?
if I apply display: block; to the input then it works, but I would like to understand why.

Does this answer your question? What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?

Or even What is the difference between display:inline and display:block?

i understood the difference what i don't understand is why display block does nothing if applied to my class "container "but works if applied to a child of the container, in the MDM docs they state that this property should be applied to the class and children so if applied to "container " should work as well but it does not work

Setting display: block; on the container doesn't automatically make its children stack vertically because <input> elements are naturally inline-block, meaning they sit side by side by default. To stack them vertically, you need to apply display: block; directly to the <input> elements.


.container input {
  display: block; 
}
<div>
  <form class="container" action="">
    <input name="fName" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value={props.fName}/>
    <input name="sName" placeholder="Second Name" type="text" value={props.sName} />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>



